# Datamatrix barcode reader/generator for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, barcode

I have found alot of .NET barcode reader/generators but not many for Ruby. Any recommendations on GEMS or someway to generate dtaamatrix barcodes and the ability to read datamatrix barcodes in PDF/TIFF files?

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same problem a few months ago. There is a gem named "semacode" which use a native extension to generate datamatrix codes but it's buggy (adds a space in front of every string).

I would suggest Libdmtx through the system command which works fine for me. Afaik there is also an ruby adapter to this library but I the shell is okay for my project.